# How to create pom.xml for openimaj?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, openimaj

I am trying to run "mvn install" as described here:

http://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20From%20Source/

I have downloaded the svn of openimaj and the pom.xml files is in:

```
C:\Users\[user]\openimaj
```

When I try to run "mvn install" it says:

```
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Users\net). Please verify you invoked Maven from the corr
ect directory. -> [Help 1]
```

I believe I need to put a my pom.xml in `C:\Users\net`, But how should I create this pom.xml for openimaj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the `mvn install` command in the directory containing the pom file. (C:\Users\[user]\openimaj instead of C:\Users\net).

Comment: Ok done. What should I do now? Should i create a project in eclipse ? Thanks

Comment: You were trying to compile the project, and you did. I have no idea why you did that or what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to get started with my java project using openimaj libraries.. that's it. I am following this guide: http://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20From%20Source/

Comment: Then just import the jar file(s) you just created with maven as a library in your java project. They should be somewhere in the target directory.

Comment: well i give up. OpenCV has much more documentation and example.

Answer (score 4):

OpenIMAJ developer here.

If you're trying to develop the project itself you are following the correct guide [OpenIMAJ from source](http://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20From%20Source/)

If however you would like to simply include OpenIMAJ in a new java project you can follow [the tutorial](http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial.pdf). Be warned that the code used in the tutorial though working, is an the latest stable release of OpenIMAJ, but the snapshot versions are much better and more up to date. We aim to make a new release in the next few weeks.

By looking at the pom generated in the tutorial you can easily copy the dependencies into your project, removing the dependencies you don't care about or perhaps using the latest snapshot version (1.0.6-SNAPSHOT).

We realise our project's documentation is a little sparse at the moment, we are trying to address this as well. If you don't mind me asking, what is your aim?

Comment: it is object detection using feature extraction and matching (sift). The main problem in the tutorial you have linked assumes one have knowledge of Maven. Instead I was able to download and create my first opencv project in minutes by following step-by-step tutorials ( http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/ )

Comment: hmm yes I understand. The issue is the with little to no knowledge of maven one should be able to follow the tutorial. As the tutorial says, one must: 1) install maven. 2) write the maven archetype command. This is far fewer steps than the blog you posted I think?

Comment: @sijax: Yea I have tried that. I don't perfectly recall but writing that maven archetype command gave me some errors I wasn't able to fix